# Realm filter results based on values in child object list

Tags: swift, realm

This is how my Realm objects look:

```
class Restaurant: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
    let meals = List<Meal>()
}

class Meal: Object {
    @objc dynamic var mealName: String? = nil
    let tag = RealmOptional<Int>()
}
```

I'm trying to fetch all meals that have some tags (I know I can filter all Realm objects of type `Meal` for specific tags), but the goal is to fetch all `Restaurant` objects and filter it's `Meal` child objects based on tag values.

I tried filtering like this:

```
restaurants = realm.objects(Restaurant.self).filter("meals.@tags IN %@", selectedTags)
```

but this won't work. Is there a way to filter results based on values in child object list?

To clarify the question, this is an example how filtering should work
for `selectedTags = [1, 2, 3]`
This is the whole `Restaurant` model that is saved in Realm.

```
[Restaurant {
    name = "Foo"
    meals = [
        Meal {
            mealName = "Meal 1"
            tag = 1
        },
        Meal {
            mealName = "Meal 2"
            tag = 2
        },
        Meal {
            mealName = "Meal 7"
            tag = 7
        }
    ]
}]
```

Filtering should return this:

```
[Restaurant {
    name = "Foo"
    meals = [
        Meal {
            mealName = "Meal 1"
            tag = 1
        },
        Meal {
            mealName = "Meal 2"
            tag = 2
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution - add a reverse refererence to the restaurant for each meal object

```
class Restaurant: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
    let meals = List<Meal>()
}

class Meal: Object {
    @objc dynamic var mealName: String? = nil
    let tag = RealmOptional<Int>()
    @objc dynamic var restaurant: Restaurant?  //Add this
}
```

then query the meals for that restaurant with the tags you want.

```
let results = realm.objects(Meal.self).filter("restaurant.name == %@ AND tag IN %@", "Foo", [1,2])
```

LinkingObjects could also be leveraged but it depends on what kind of queries will be needed and what the relationships are between Restaurants and Meals - I am assuming 1-Many in this case.

if you want ALL restaurants, then LinkingObjects is the way to go.

**Edit:**

Thought of another solution. This will work without adding a reference or an inverse relationship and will return an array of restaurants that have meals with the selected tags.

```
let selectedTags = [1,2]
let results = realm.objects(Restaurant.self).filter( {
    for meal in $0.meals {
        if let thisTag = meal.tag.value { //optional so safely unwrap it
            if selectedTags.contains(thisTag) {
                return true //the tag for this meal was in the list, return true
            }
        } else {
            return false //tag was nil so return false
        }
    }
    return false
})
```

Comment: The second solution worked like a charm, totally forgot about the custom filter method, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot do what you are asking. Not within a Realm query (and therefore benefit from update notifications if that is important) at least. No doubt you can make some kind of structure containing what you want though via non-Realm filtering.

To better answer, let's first consider what you're trying to produce as a query result. As you say, your attempt above won't work. But you're trying to filter `Restaurant`s by having some `Meal`s matching some criteria; this is probably achievable, but your resulting query on `Restaurant` type would then produce a list of `Restaurant`s. Each restaurant would still have a natural property of all its `Meal`s, and would require the same filter applied again to the meals.

It makes sense though to add a function (if you need the search criteria to be dynamic, use a computed property if the filter is always the same tags) to the `Restaurant` class that produces a view of its `Meal`s matching your criteria.

e.g.

```
extension Restaurant
{
  var importantMeals : Results<Meal>
  {
    return meals.filter(...)
  }
}
```

So I think there are two options.

1. Iterate through all `Restaurant` objects, and add it to a data structure of your own (Set or array) if its `importantMeals` property is not empty. Then use the same property to produce the meal list when needed. Or you could use a non-Realm filter to produce that query for you. E.g. `realm.objects(Restaurant.self).compactMap {$0}.filter { !$0.importantMeals.isEmpty }`
2. Alternatively, filter all `Meal`s according to your criteria (`realm.objects(Meal.self).filter(...)`). You could then add a `LinkingObjects` property to your `Meal` class to make the Set of `Restaurant`s with relevant `Meal`s.

The correct approach will depend on how you want to use the results, but I'd suggest approach 1 will see you right. Note that you might want to sort the results produced by queries before using if order is of any importance to you (e.g. for displaying in `UITableView`) as there is no guarantee that the order of objects will be the same for each query performed.